# Derivatives of sin wave function with respect to amplitude, frequency, and horizontal/vertical shifts?

Tags: partial-derivative

I am trying to find the derivatives of a sine wave function $$f(x,A,F,H,V) = A\sin(F(x-H))+V$$ with respect to each variable, where $A$ is amplitude, $F$ is frequency, $H$ is horizontal shift, and $V$ is vertical shift. So far I believe I have correctly found the derivatives with respect to amplitude and vertical shift.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = \sin(F(x-H))$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial V} = 1$

However I am having trouble finding the derivative with respect to frequency and horizontal shift. Kindly let me know how I should go about this and let me know if I have made any errors in derivatives with respect to amplitude and vertical shift.

Comment: Do you know what the derivative of $\sin$ is?

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how to do the partial derivative with respect to $F$ and leave $H$ as an exercise.

$$\begin{align*} \frac\partial{\partial F} \big(A\sin(F(x-H))+V\big) &= 
A\frac\partial{\partial F} \sin(F(x-H)) + 0 \quad \text{(linearity)}\\
&= A\cos(F(x-H))\frac\partial{\partial F}(F(x-H)) \quad \text{(chain rule)}\\
&=A\cos(F(x-H))(x-H).
\end{align*}$$